# counting the number of values greater than 0 in R in multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset

I have a dataset myDF in R with a the variables L1,L2,L3,L4. How can I get the number of observations in L2, L3, and L4 that area greater than 0?

I would like to use the subset function, I'm just not sure how 
Thanks!

```
L1     L2     L3    L4
1       1     0     2
2       1     4     1 
3       1     3     1
2       2     1     1
```

I would like to be able to create a function that would be able to tally up the number of rows in columns L2, L3, and L4 greater than 0.

Comment: `sapply(myDF[c("L3","L2","L4"], function(x) sum(x>0))`

Comment: `sum(myDF[,c("L2","L3","L4")]>0)`

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi I would like to count the number of rows in those certain columns that have variables > 0. I do not want to add up the variables in each of the columns. Thanks!

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi Thank you that works. However, I do have another question that has to do with this problem, but I think I will create a new question since it is quite a bit different than what I was asking here. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use

```
colSums(myDF[c("L2", "L3", "L4")] > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `colSums` will give you the right answer since it doesn't counts the number of observations, but only sums the columns' values.

I think that this will give you what you want , I hope.

```
apply(myDF,2,function(x) sum(x > 0))
```

Comment: The way it is done in the accepted answer does work, since the ```> 0``` transforms all values larger than 0 to ```TRUE``` and all smaller than zero to ```FALSE``` which are then interpreted as ```1``` and ```0``` by ```colSums()```. Just in case someone wonders.